# jquery reload div inside dynamic bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to refresh a DIV inside an open bootstrap modal through button with Load Function from JQuery, but div is hidden when click button.

*More specifically, I want to include a comment box inside that module.

```
        $("body").delegate("#ajax_comment_submit", "submit", function(){
            $.ajax({

                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),                  
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    $("#ajax_comment_div").load(" #ajax_comment_div");
                }
            });         
            
            return false;
            
        });
```

Comment: *div is hidden when click button*? Or the whole page refresh??

Comment: no, when click button

Comment: I mean, instead of being updated, it just disappears

Comment: on success `console.log(data)` first and comment the `//.load()` line .. then see what you'll get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let's start from the beginning

- Typing the comment .. Then click submit
- Using ajax to save the comment to whereever database,localstorage,...
- Retreive the data with all comments/new comment on success to append it to the comment div

So the success:..(data) should hold all the comments OR only new comment

For both ways you don't need to use `.load(` .. You'll need to use `.html(` OR `.append(` and that's rely on how you return the data to the ajax success

- If you return all comments in HTML format you'll need to use `.html("data / All comments Here")`
- If you return the new comment only in HTML format you'll need to use `.append("data / new comment here")`

If you return the data in other format you'll need `.append(` with some javascript HTML to append comment by comment or even to append only the new one